# CALayer autoresizingMask not for iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-core

I noticed, what CALayer, on iOS SDK haven't autoresizingMask property. I'm not sure what custom overloading of method "setFrame:" can work normally with animated sublayers autoresizing.  Are there is an alternative without using UIView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use layoutSublayers function of calayer.

Answer (score 9):

If you do not want to subclass `CALayer` and added the layer to the layer of a `UIView` then you can override

> - (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer

method of view.