# How to resize a CAGradientLayer after rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cagradientlayer

I'm adding a `CAGradientLayer` to a view. When the view is auto-resized (such as after a rotation) the gradient layer is not resized. Can the gradient be set to auto-resize the same as the view? Note also that I am using auto-layout constraints in the view.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0f green:255.0/255.0f blue:255.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:233.0/255.0f green:233.0/255.0f blue:233.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor], nil];

    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CALayer autoresizingMask not for iOS SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600826/calayer-autoresizingmask-not-for-ios-sdk)

Comment: @CodaFi Slightly different question. Also, although there is an accepted answer for that question it's seemingly useless for this case.

Comment: You're right, that answer is worthless.  Override `-layoutSubviews` and assign your frames in there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are two different ways to fix your problem.

1. Make `gradientLayer` an instance variable instead of a local variable.  Then, override `layoutSubviews` in your view class to set the frame of the gradient layer:

   ```
   - (void)layoutSubviews {
       [super layoutSubviews];
       _gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
   }
   ```
2. Create a subclass of `UIView` named `GradientView`, and override its `+layerClass` method to return `[CAGradientLayer class]`.  Use this view to draw your gradient instead of using a layer directly.  Then set the gradient view's `autoresizingMask` (or add constraints to it if you are using auto layout).  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558724/77567) for an example.

Creating the `GradientView` class will also make the resizing behave correctly during rotation, so I recommend that solution.

Comment: ♡ the linked answer. Great explanation of the problem (with animated gif!) and solution. Well done.

Comment: The included link made the explanation super simple! Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 2):

I resize the layer's bounds manually by overriding the `setFrame:` method of the view:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    _gradientLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));
}
```

Comment: `setFrame:` unfortunately is not called during events like rotation, so this won't work.