# CAGradientLayer, not resizing nicely, tearing on rotation SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swift, cagradientlayer

So I'm working on a iOS application written in Swift and I came across this exact same issue as this:

[CAGradientLayer not resizing nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555986/cagradientlayer-not-resizing-nicely-tearing-on-rotation-video-of-issue-attac)

I add a CAGradientLayer to my UIView and I override willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation in order to update the gradient bounds. This only seems to update AFTER the rotation is complete and thus you see the bounds of the original frame when rotating (which causes the user to see the white background of my app).

Here is my code:

in viewDidLoad, I have the following code:

```
    var color1: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0.12), green: CGFloat(0.13), blue: CGFloat(0.70), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    var color2: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0.00), green: CGFloat(0.59), blue: CGFloat(1.00), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    var color3: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0.00), green: CGFloat(1.00), blue: CGFloat(1.00), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))

    let gradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let arrayColors: [AnyObject] = [color1.CGColor, color2.CGColor, color3.CGColor]

    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradient.colors = arrayColors
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

and I override this function:

```
    override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        var gradient:CAGradientLayer = self.view.layer.sublayers[0] as CAGradientLayer
        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
```

The solution is seems to be this:

```
// GradientView.h

@interface GradientView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CAGradientLayer *layer;

@end

// GradientView.m

@implementation GradientView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

@end
```

But I'm having a really hard time converting this class to Swift. Can someone help me? So far I have this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GradientView:UIView
{
    var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    func layerClass() -> CAGradientLayer {
        return gradientLayer.self
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm not understanding what would be the Swift equivalent of the 'class' message being used in [CAGradientLayer class]?

I've been trying to make this work for a few hours now and I just can't seem to get it. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `layerClass()` class method, and return a class:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
}
```

At some point, you will also want to set your `gradientLayer` property to `self.layer`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I put in my example above.