# ios background color only appears on half of screen in landscape mode

Tags: ios, background, landscape-portrait

I am currently using the following method to set the background color of my view

```
 //Set the background color
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient]; <---Calls method below
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    //self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

This is how it obtains the gradient color - this is the method is called above

```
@implementation BackgroundLayer
//Blue gradient background
+ (CAGradientLayer*) blueGradient {

    UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:(120/255.0) green:(135/255.0) blue:(150/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255.0)  green:(79/255.0)  blue:(96/255.0)  alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
    NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];

    CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    headerLayer.colors = colors;
    headerLayer.locations = locations;

    return headerLayer;
}

@end
```

Now in the portrait mode the background appears fine. However in Landscape mode it only covers half the screen and the other half is white. Why is that ? And how can I fix it. I tried the following for changing the color

```
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

The above works fine both in landscape an portrait mode however its not a gradient. Any ideas on how I can make the gradient work ?

Comment: Hi,James,See my update, I post a better way to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy way:**

Just Add this to your viewcontroller

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    self.bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

**Better way:**

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555986/cagradientlayer-not-resizing-nicely-tearing-on-rotation-video-of-issue-attac)Describe, you can do it in this way.I test it with My Xcode,it works fine.

1. Define a background view to manage size

.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface BackgrundView : UIView

    @end
```

.m file

```
    #import "BackgrundView.h"      
    @interface BackgrundView()
    @end
    @implementation BackgrundView
    +(Class)layerClass{
        return [CAGradientLayer class];
    }
    @end
```

2 Set up what you want

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BackgrundView.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property BackgrundView * backgroundview;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.backgroundview = [[BackgrundView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.backgroundview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:self.backgroundview];
    UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:(120/255.0) green:(135/255.0) blue:(150/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255.0)  green:(79/255.0)  blue:(96/255.0)  alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
    NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];
    CAGradientLayer * graintLayer = (CAGradientLayer *)self.backgroundview.layer;
    graintLayer.colors = colors;
    graintLayer.locations = locations;
}
```

Comment: self.bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

Answer (score 0):

Correct line of code is: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the frame of the Background layer when the device rotates to Landscape?
Apparently your problem can be solved from the answer in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555986/cagradientlayer-not-resizing-nicely-tearing-on-rotation-video-of-issue-attac)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new gradient when your device rotates.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews // called when device rotates
{
    [self.bgLayer removeFromSuperlayer]; // you need to keep reference so you can remove the old layer

    self.bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient]; <---Calls method below
    self.bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

look @WenchenHuang answer, its better than my approach.

Comment: bgLayer does not have the method removeFromSuperLayer

Comment: sorry It is removeFromSuperlayer

Comment: I put a breakpoint here and this method gets called on the start too. Could you explain a little. What this method does ?

Comment: `When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.` It is called multiple times after view did load and when your device changes its rotation.