# CALayer does not autoresizing with gradient color for different orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, orientation, cagradientlayer

I'm creating some custom view programmatically with auto layout constraints and want to set a gradient color as the background color of the custom view. It seems if i don't set a frame for the custom view then no background color appear for the custom view. If i set a frame then background gradient color appear only for the frame size but does not resize to the view bounds as well as for different orientation. What should i do for resizing the CALayer to the view's bounds with different orientation support ? I tried like below -

```
- (void) addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView:(UIView *)view {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view.bounds;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];

    [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    //[view.layer addSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}

- (void)addCustomViewAsRow {

    UIView *lastView;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.layer.bounds.size.width - 20, 50)];

        //If i uncomment the following line and comment out the previous line then nothing appears as background color

        //UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

        //Adding gradient color to the custom view
        [self addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView:view];

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[view]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:-20.0]];

        if (i == 0) {
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];
        } else {
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lastView(50)]-10-[view(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lastView, view)]];
        }

        lastView = view;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self addCustomViewAsRow];
}
```

### EDITED :

i also tried like below code snippet but does not working for me -

In my TestViewController.m -

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "GradientView.h"

#define DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT 50

@interface TestViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAGradientLayer *gradientView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView:(UIView *)view {

    self.gradientView = [[GradientView layerClass] layer];
    self.gradientView.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];

    //[view.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientView atIndex:0];

    [view.layer addSublayer:self.gradientView];

}

- (void) addCustomViewAsRow {

    UIView *lastView;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {

        //UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.layer.bounds.size.width -20, 50)];

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

        //Adding gradient color to the custom view
        [self addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView:view];

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        //Adding horizontal layout for the custom view
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[view]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:-20.0]];

        //Adding vertical layout for the custom view
        if (i == 0) {
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];
        } else {
            [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lastView(50)]-10-[view(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lastView, view)]];
        }

        lastView = view;

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //self.gradientView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self addCustomViewAsRow];
}

@end
```

In GradientView.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GradientView : UIView

+(Class) layerClass;

@end
```

In GradientView.m -

```
#import "GradientView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation GradientView

+(Class) layerClass {

    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

@end
```

Comment: Use a view to manage your gradient. [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17558724/77567)

Comment: I tried that way but that does not working for me. I was forget to post addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView method in my post but now i've edited that. Can you see please now and let me know what should i do ?...@rob mayoff

Comment: You should take my advice and use the `GradientView` class from that answer. If it doesn't work, explain what happens when you use a `GradientView`.

Comment: Dear Rob Mayoff, i also followed your suggestion and updated my post to show you how i implemented this, but unfortunately that also doesn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a view to manage your `CAGradientLayer`. Copy the `GradientView` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558724/77567), and use it like this:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void) addGradientBackgroundColorToCustomView:(UIView *)view {
    GradientView *gradientView = [[GradientView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    gradientView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    CAGradientLayer *layer = (CAGradientLayer *)gradientView.layer;
    layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];

    [view addSubview:gradientView];
}
```