# How do I use a different layer for UIView's layer object, like this answer states?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, calayer

I saw an answer where a user mentioned replacing the CALayer class for a UIView. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558724/998117

But if I add that property, I get

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'layer'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention.

How should I be replacing this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message/warning that you're getting is telling you that you've declared a property called *layer , but you are already inheriting a property with the same name.  So you can eliminated this warning by doing what it says, insert @dynamic layer at the start of your implementation, or just remove the declaration of this *layer property and use the existing one.

You can change the layer that a UIView subclass automatically creates by overriding

```
-(class)layerClass
```

And returning your own subclass of CALayer.

Best