# CABasicAnimation is slowly down my app

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am experiencing low performance when adding a CABasicAnimation. My app is slowing down. If I remove it, everything is smooth.
I have tried to put animation in a background thread using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^() {
});
```

but no luck.
What can I do?
Here is the code I used to create the animation.
Thanks a lot!

```
NSArray *fromColors = gradientLayer.colors;
NSArray *toColors = [self chooseGradientColors:flag];

[gradientLayer setColors:toColors];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"colors"];

animation.fromValue = fromColors;
animation.toValue = toColors;
animation.duration = kGradientDuration;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

//Add the animation to layer
[gradientLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateGradient"];
```

Comment: also can you attach misaligned image screen shot ?

Comment: Instead of screenshot I have to upload video to let you know problems I am experimenting, as I have implemented dynamic gradient basing on code above. It works good, but when I try to show keyboard related to textfield, for instance, this action is very slow due to gradient.
I do not know if I am allowed to upload video.

Comment: i have had a problem like this when i was working with streching header in tableView, at that instance gradient was not streching with same velocity/ or say very slow. is your prob something like it ? This fix my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555986/cagradientlayer-not-resizing-nicely-tearing-on-rotation-video-of-issue-attac

Comment: Sorry man. This was not the actual problem. My problem is related to CABasicAnimation as I wrote. Anyway, I will have a try. Thank you.

Comment: Just tried. Unfortunately no luck. Because problem was not that. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` and see if improve performance.

i have use this link to fix my problem may be help you [CAGradientLayer, not resizing nicely, tearing on rotation. (video of issue attached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555986/cagradientlayer-not-resizing-nicely-tearing-on-rotation-video-of-issue-attac) thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with that.
I have added
gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
but nothing changed.

Any other idea?